# Change image in div by clicking another - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm going to create a colour picker for a product. I have 12 colour options and hence 12 photographs to display.

I'd like it to look like this Flash page:

http://www.renault.co.uk/cars/model/newmeganehatch/colourselector.aspx

I would much prefer to use jQuery though.

I'm thinking of using row of divs to contain the colours and invoking a change of image in the main picture-container div on colour click.

Would I be better off stacking the images and using display:none or would it be better to use a plugin such as jQuery cycle?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED TO SHOW CODE TO DATE:

```
<!--The color picker div-->
<div class="picker p1" data-bkgnd="images/1.jpg"></div>
<div class="picker p2" data-bkgnd="images/2.jpg"></div>
<div class="picker p3" data-bkgnd="images/3.jpg"></div>

<!--The container for the product image-->
<div class="productdisplay"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".picker").click(function(){

           //Load background string from data of clicked element
           var bVal = $(this).data('bkgnd');

           //Set display's background to retrieved background string
           $(".productdisplay").hide('fade').css({'background-image': "url('" + bVal + "')"}).show('fade');
       });
     });
    </script>
```

and the CSS

```
.productdisplay {
height:327px;
width:590px;
float:left;
background-image:url('images/1.jpg');
}
.picker {
height:50px;
width:50px;
float:left;
}
.p1 {
background:#FFF;
}
.p2 {
background:#C4C9C5;
}
.p3 {
background:#988879;
}
```

Currently getting 'Undefined' as the URL when loading the bVal data into the div, can't see why.

Comment: Because this is quite easy task I'd propose to implement it from scratch, not using ready plugins. You will learn jQuery while implementing it. Take a look at jQuery documentation, namely at `click()` and `attr()` (or if you prefer stacking of pre-loaded images, `toggle()`) functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at those. The plugin was more to add nice transitions to the images like the Flash example I gave.

Comment: Oh, these simple effects can be implemented with stock jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could get you started:

```
//The color picker div    
<div class="picker" data-bkgnd="/content/images/someimg.jpg"></div>

//The container for your product image
<div class="productDisplay"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".picker").click(function(){       
       //Load background string from data of clicked element
       var bVal = $(this).attr('data-bkgnd');
       //Set display's background to retrieved background string
       $(".productDisplay").hide().css({'background-image': "url(" + bVal + ")"}).show();
   });
 });

</script>
```

[Click here to view the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/M9ysa/3/)

Comment: OK, I get it thanks. Is it worth pre-loading the images somehow? I'd also love to add some slick transition to it like a fade in/out.

Comment: You could pre-load, save time once the page is rendered.  Updated with  fade in/out calls.  Also, if this was the solution for you, would you mind clicking the checkbox beside my answer?  Thank you!

Comment: Used your code TNCodeMonkey to create a page. It won't load the bVal data though, even though the path is correct. I put a start image in the div which works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Corrected issue with data-bkgnd and added fiddle for you, this should work :)

Comment: That's great thanks! Just need to work on the loading of the images now and adding some nice effects.